# Arrays and functions in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, return-value

I am working with array of chars. My function is expected to return an array. Then I expect to assign that array to a different `char array`.

e.g. I have

```
char somechar[50];
```

in Class declaration, it is private.

I defined a get method as :

```
char getsomechar(){
    return somechar;
}
```

in my main function, I am trying to:
 access it assign as:

```
char newchar[]=getsomechar();
```

I was given return type and function type do not match. So I corrected second line to:

```
char *getsomechar(){
    return somechar;
}
```

However I am still having `initialization with {...} expected for aggregate object` error. I read some pages and saw that you cannot pass array by value in C++. I can't use array library. How do I do it with pointers/references?

Comment: Note that you don't "return arrays" in C/C++, traditionally you return pointers to arrays. Are you meant to be allocating a new array on the heap?

Comment: Use char* newchar=getsomechar(). Since you have assigned pointer to newchar, the memory has been allocated (which you would otherwise do using malloc). Now you can access the index as you would do for a  regular array, newchar[0] and so on. brokenfoot has the right answer.

Comment: If you are trying to handle strings, then `std::string` supports copying and much else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially returing a pointer to the array in your funciton:

```
return somechar;  //this is the starting address of the array
```

So, you should declare a `char*` and assign the starting address of the array to it, like so :

```
char* newchar=getsomechar();
```

and now you can access this pointer, like an array by indexing:

```
for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
{
    newchar[i] = value // whatever operation you want to do here
}
```